# Socket works on emulator not on device

Tags: android, sockets, emulation, device, connect

I have an app that works on the emulator but not when tested on real device. 
Whole program:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Socket socket;
    String strg;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        connect();
    }
    private void connect()
    {
        socket = null;
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("xx.xx.xx.xx");
                    socket = new Socket(serverAddr, x);
                    strg = "ok";
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.output)).setText(strg);
                        }
                    });
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    final IOException exp = e;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            strg = "ex2 "+exp.getMessage();
                            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.output)).setText(strg);
                        }
                    });                     
                }                   
            }
        });
        t.start();  
    }
}
```

So this i all code there is. 
 
I connect to an external IP which only can accept the connection. 
When i run on the emulator `strg` is "ok" and the server registers that a connection has been established. 
When i run the code on the device i get error message. `"java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /xx.xx.xx.xx (port x): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)"`

I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` & 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` (Otherwise it won't work on the emulator.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure your port number is starting from `10.0.2.2` when running on Android.

Comment: You try to use an external ip address. Ok. And the message is clear. It fails to connect. Find out why. Is the used port not forwarded in the router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution and it was wrong settings on the server firewall which was blocking my requests. Thanks greenapps :)

Answer (score 0):

Read something about [StrictMode](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/04/04/android-strictmode/). You can't perform long operation in UI (disk, memory, network). Emulator is less strict as real device.

Comment: He does not need that as he already uses a thread. Moreover never advertise StrictMode. Advertise to use an AsyncTask or Thread.